# How can I display only one list represented from the display function?

Tags: c, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Basically I have 10 files named src(=source) and each of them has packets (named so for my homework) which are represented by roll number, dest(=destination) and gentime (=generation time). I want to have one list for each file, so 10 different lists, that will pass the packets in. But, when I display them, I have to have the option to display only one list, for example list 3, which will be for src file 3. My code is below.

```
void output( Node **head )
{
    for( Node *current =*head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        //printf( "%d %d %d %0.1f ",current->rollnumber, current->src, current->dst, current->gentime );
        printf("Roll Number:%2d\t",current->rollnumber);
        printf("src:%2d\t", current->src);
        printf("dest:%2d\t", current->dst);
        printf("gentime:%0.1f\n", current->gentime);
    }
    printf( "%s\n", "NULL" );
}

void display( Node **set, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        output( set++ );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
NULL

Roll Number: 8  src: 1  dest:10 gentime:89.1
Roll Number: 7  src: 1  dest:12 gentime:76.5
Roll Number: 6  src: 1  dest:10 gentime:64.1
Roll Number: 5  src: 1  dest: 4 gentime:51.5
Roll Number: 4  src: 1  dest:17 gentime:38.0
Roll Number: 3  src: 1  dest:20 gentime:25.9
Roll Number: 2  src: 1  dest:15 gentime:13.9
Roll Number: 1  src: 1  dest: 3 gentime:1.6
NULL

Roll Number: 8  src: 2  dest:12 gentime:90.6
Roll Number: 7  src: 2  dest: 6 gentime:78.1
Roll Number: 6  src: 2  dest:17 gentime:64.8
Roll Number: 5  src: 2  dest: 6 gentime:52.6
Roll Number: 4  src: 2  dest: 5 gentime:39.5
Roll Number: 3  src: 2  dest:20 gentime:26.0
Roll Number: 2  src: 2  dest:19 gentime:14.0
Roll Number: 1  src: 2  dest: 4 gentime:1.9
NULL

Roll Number: 8  src: 3  dest: 5 gentime:89.8
Roll Number: 7  src: 3  dest: 1 gentime:75.9
Roll Number: 6  src: 3  dest: 8 gentime:63.9
Roll Number: 5  src: 3  dest:14 gentime:50.8
Roll Number: 4  src: 3  dest:11 gentime:38.4
Roll Number: 3  src: 3  dest:16 gentime:25.7
Roll Number: 2  src: 3  dest:18 gentime:13.4
Roll Number: 1  src: 3  dest: 7 gentime:1.2
NULL
```

and so goes on until src:10

Also, the push function:

```
int push_front( Node **head, int rollnumber, int src, int dst, double gentime )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->rollnumber=rollnumber;
        new_node->src = src;
        new_node->dst=dst;
        new_node->gentime=gentime;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Code that calls display: (please don't mind the variables I have not mentioned, they have to do with another part of my code, just for checking).

```
for (i=1;i<=10;i++){
            printf("intention[%d]=%d\n",i,intention[i]);
            if (intention[i]=true){
                printf("link[%d]:\n",i);
                display( link, sizeof( link ) / sizeof( *link ) );
            }
        }
```

How is it possible to display only one list whenever I call the function?
Can anyone please tell me how to proceed?

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define N   10

typedef struct Node 
{
    int rollnumber, src, dst;
    double gentime;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

int push_front( Node **head, int rollnumber, int src, int dst, double gentime )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->rollnumber=rollnumber;
        new_node->src = src;
        new_node->dst=dst;
        new_node->gentime=gentime;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
void output( Node **head )
{
    for( Node *current =*head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d %d %d %0.1f ",current->rollnumber, current->src, current->dst, current->gentime );
        
    }
    printf( "%s\n", "NULL" );
}

void display( Node **set, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        output( set++ );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int src,dst;
    int rollnumber;
    double gentime;
    Node * link[N] = { 0 };
    struct node * head = NULL;
     for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
       //reading from a file : rollnumber, src, dst, gentime
       push_front( &link[i], rollnumber, src, dst, gentime );
       printf("link[%d]:\n",i);
                display( link, sizeof( link ) / sizeof( *link ) );
            }
}
```

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry for forgetting that, just edit!

Comment: You call `display` 10 times, so it's pretty normal that all 10 lists are displayed. Just call `display` for the lists you want to display.

Comment: `if (intention[i]=true){` doesn't look good. Add an `=` so you get the comparison operator `==`, or remove the `=true` completely.

Comment: @Jabberwocky that is exactly what I want to do, but when I simply write : display( link, sizeof( link ) / sizeof( *link ) ); it also displays all of them

Comment: @mmixLinus thank you for noticing, I'll try it

Comment: @wajaap what is `link`. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I do not know how to write one of them, but I have link as: Node * link[N] = { 0 };

Comment: You don't know how to produce a [mcve]? There is not much to know, just some work for you.

Comment: I tried it with ==, but it has not to do with that. Also displays all of them. For a minimal reproducible example do I have to write a different question?

Comment: I assume that `N` in `Node * link[N] = { 0 };` is a constant `10`. So `sizeof( link ) / sizeof( *link ) )` is 10 and `display( link, sizeof( link ) / sizeof( *link ) )` will display all 10 lists.

Comment: No, just [edit] the question and add the [mcve] into this question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes it is as you assumed. Should I change that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240928/discussion-between-jabberwocky-and-wajaap).

Comment: @Jabberwocky ok, I'm fixxing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)` : array indexes start with 0, not with 1, so it should be `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`
2. There should not be a loop in `display`, you tell `display` which one of the lists in the array should be displayed, and that's all it should do.
3. Minor problem: `output` should get a `Node* head`, not a `Node** head`, because it only reads from the list, it does not modify the list.
4. Minor problem: don't use `10` but `N`.

Corrected code (as [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with irrelevant code stripped and with fake test data):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define N   10

typedef struct Node
{
  int data;
  struct Node* next;
} Node;


int push_front(Node** head, int data)
{
  Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  int success = new_node != NULL;

  if (success)
  {
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
  }

  return success;
}

void output(Node* head)
{
  for (Node* current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
  {
    printf("%d ", current->data);
  }
}

void display(Node** set, int i)
{
    output(set[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
  int testdata = 1;
  Node* link[N] = { 0 };
  struct node* head = NULL;

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    push_front(&link[i], testdata++);
    push_front(&link[i], testdata++);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("link[%d]:", i);
    display(link, i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is it possible from each set to print the first node and not the whole link?